# Propagating User intent in PlatForm UI events

Tags: aem

Let us say that we have two buttons "Create Foo" and "Edit Foo". Both of them use the same Dialog for Foo but we want to show different fields depending on whether the user intended to create or edit. What is the best practice in propagating the user intent in Platform UI? (It appears that we are unable to access the dialog object in the button click event and thus have to manipulate the dialog in the coral before-open event).

Comment: *...Both of them use the same Dialog for Foo but we want to show different fields...* - this smells of bad design, if fields are different, use a different dialog.

Comment: To clarify we want to show a subset of fields for edit and show all fields for create.